# Wordpress redirect page template for mobile devices

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, redirect

I'm currently working on a Wordpress web and i want to use a different template for a page when a user sees it on a mobile device. For example I have a page called Proyects that uses the template gallery.php but if somebody sees it in a mobile device the same page Proyects use the template gallery_mobile.php.  I don't know if is something you put it in the template (ie page.php) or in the functions.php.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for mobile use [`wp_is_mobile`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile), to perform a redirect, hook into [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect):

```
function so16778006_mobile_redirect()
{
    if( is_page( 'proyects' ) && wp_is_mobile() )
    {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/gallery_mobile.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16778006_mobile_redirect' );
```